# Enabling ICEfaces compat leads to not recognizing h:head and h:body

Tags: icefaces

I'm working on an ICEfaces 3 application and I have the following XHTML file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
    xmlns:icecore="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/core"
    xmlns:ace="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/components"
    >
<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="template/main-template.xhtml"> ... </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Using this template without icefaces-compat included in the WAR works well (as long as I only use ACE components obviously). But now I like to use some of the ice: components and therefore need the -compat JAR. But when adding this JAR to the WAR the following error occurs:

```
12.04.2012 13:56:32 org.icefaces.impl.event.BridgeSetup isListenerForSource
WARNING: ICEfaces configured for view /configuration.xhtml but h:head and h:body components are required
```

This error also occurs when I completely remove the `ui:composition` tag from the side, i.e. the `<h:body>` tag is empty.

I'm happy to provide further information but right now I'm not sure what is important as the only difference that I do is that I add the -compat library to the WAR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally came up with the very simple solution: I forgot to add the WEB-INF/faces-config.xml file. This seems to be fine as long as ACE etc is used, but as soon as the -compat jars are used, it seems to be necessary. The file itself needs to only include:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
          version="2.0">
</faces-config>
```